# Switching from ADFS to password sync, how to check dependencies

Tags: active-directory, domain, entra-id, adfs

Is there a way to check if there is any dependencies on swichting from ADFS => PHS? 
We are doing migration of another company into ours, and in that regard want to get rid of their ADFS. 
Changeing the setting to PHS, seems straightforward.

I am worried that there might be some dependencies which does not support PHS, but is it possible to check before the switch?

Comment: I don’t think Office has any issues with changing. You can check the ADFS server though for any other “relying parties” that are configured to use this server for authentication. ADFS may be used for more than just Office 365. Make sure you also setup and understand MFA, because it might be handled by ADFS too.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this aswell after some more research yesterday evening. 
There is no other relying parties. thankfully